# java-based tool to reduce the number of css rules

Tags: java, css, duplicates

IE is not able to handle more than 4096 css rules. This limit is biting me. So I'm looking for a tool that can identify duplicate css rules and merge them. Doesn't matter much if the result is bigger in size, the point is to have less css rules.

This is not a css compressor question, but a css rules number reduction question.

Comment: Most (?) compressors also reduce rules.

Comment: there is a ruby based tool http://code.google.com/p/css-redundancy-checker/

Comment: @Cloudanger i belive css compressor tool will want to things like :
p, input, span {foo: bar;} in order to reduce size, but that increases the number of rules. My priority is to reduce the number of rules. The tool should output only 1 rule per selector.

Comment: @Redlab your tool is great, but it is not doing what I have described. Your tool ditches unused css based on provided html (a bit like the dust-me extension for firefox), whilst I am looking for a tool that reduces each selector to one rule.

Comment: I found one tool that apparently does what I have described, but it is .exe based on .net : http://cssmerge.sourceforge.net/Objective.html#Topic3
I'd like the same stuff, java-based.

Comment: also, cssmerge just breaks when i try to run it.

Comment: we keep on looking for a java based tool !

Comment: holy kill, IE limits everything. :O

Comment: I wonder how you can have more than 4096 unique css rules into a single page?!

Comment: @Rodrigo sometimes a single page is a complete webapplication. There is different teams delivering different parts of the application, and all contributing to the overall mass of css rules. Hence the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

There is a css parser in Java. It is probably not much of an effort to create a tool which merges rules if they have the same selectors to a single one and writes it to a new css file.

http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/

Comment: seems very interesting, we're having a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/)?

It's able to merge rules into single statements apart from other optimizations.

Comment: I tested it. It does the job, but it also does other non-asked things. It exists in php and C++, but unfortunately not java.

Answer (score -1):

GWT optimizes all the CSS rules. If you switch over to GWT then probably u wouldn't have to worry about anything.

Comment: Read the question, not just the title.